# Changing the BabbleTimeout and EndSilence Timeout in the Microsoft.ProjectOxford.SpeechRecognition Object

Tags: vb.net, speech-recognition, speech, azure-cognitive-services

I create the object like so:

```
Dim WithEvents m As Microsoft.ProjectOxford.SpeechRecognition.MicrophoneRecognitionClient
```

I load it like so:

```
m = SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory.CreateMicrophoneClient(SpeechRecognitionMode.LongDictation, "en-us", Key, Key2)
```

How do I adjust the `silenceTimeout` for the dictation?

It's default is like 15-20 seconds which is WAY too long.
Shortphrase doesn't work with what I'm looking to do which is to create a natural sounding conversation between the recognizer and the user.

Comment: thank you for the inquiry. Currently we do not have a way to do this in current SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Currently we do not have a way to do this in current SDK

Comment: is there a work around? Are there plans to add this?